Integration of an Angular app into index.php by using a tag
I have to embed an Angular app into a index.pxp file by using a specific tag. At the moment, is done by using Angular JS.
The question is independent from the language / system of the host page or other technology.
My goal is, instead that old "app", to put a new "app-ng" and to put a tag which loads that new app-ng into the index.php. How can I do it?

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

This doesn't seem to have much to do with PHP, which runs server-side. You seem to be trying to put your angular's JS code into a HTML document, essentially. I'm not familiar with Angular, but don't they provide documentation for things like this?

Indeed @ADyson, you right, should be more connected to Angular. Just to provide complete information, I decided to give also detail about the part in Php. No, they don't provide specific things for that.
I loaded a screenshot just because my purpose is not to provide a specific line of code, instruction of command; but just to give an idea about the structure.
Thanks for the effort; someone has a solution?

Nevertheless it is generally easier for people to help you if they can re-use your initial code in their answers/demos/tests easily, without having to type it out again. That's why we provide guidance on it in various places.

Again I'm not an Angular expert, but did none of these help you at all?

No, already tried. As said, thanks for your time.
Someone else?

You tried all those ideas?

Don't you have a runable version of your new app, that works "outside" of the index.php already? I really can't tell here right now, whether your problem has anything to do with PHP, or whether you don't know how to properly set up your app at all ...?

@CBroe thank you very much for your reply. I tried with a absolutely basic app - just by creating it by ng new name_app. I agree, has not to do with php (I put this just to provide a full picture) and sure nothing to do with the Angular app itself. I know how to set up an Angular app, just I never in the past integrated in another page in a way like that. 100% the problem is in the way to embed a generic Angular Application into another web page, by using exactly that system (a tag). Thanks again.

Just, I would need a idea like, this is the Angular basic app - without nothing else than the element created by ng new), this is a generic html page, this is the way to integrate the first in the second by using a tag. Nothing else. Thanks again, I agree with your considerations.

"I tried with a absolutely basic app - just by creating it by ng new name_app." - and that did not result in the creation of an index.htm, that contains the necessary code to load and initialize the app ...? If not, then how would you actually be able to run it?

No, I have to embed the entire app in an index.php file. Maybe we didn't understand each other.
The point is:
I have to embed an Angular app inside another web page external to the app
Thanks

But why do you want to do that? Normally an Angular app like that is supposed to be a standalone front-end user interface, with a separate backend API that it talks to, possibly hosted in a different place. But as CBroe says, surely you can make a basic app, just by following a tutorial which works in its own index.html file. Why not just take that file and rename it index.php, and go from there? You can add back in anything else that was in the original .php file (from your picture that appears to be a really minimal amount of stuff).

I'd assume you're aiming for something like https://github.com/lmame/Angular-HelloWorld/blob/master/src/index.html or or https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular-HelloWorld/blob/main/src/index.html . Rename the file to .php and off you go. Have we missed something?

You could use Angular custom elements (web components) to achieve this. I have a blog post about running AngularJS and Angular 17 side-by-side: https://johnfewell.com/blog/angularjs-angular17. Here's an example of running an Angular custom element inside of a regular HTML file from the project: https://github.com/johnfewell/angularjs-angular17/blob/main/angularjs/index.html
Setting up Angular custom elements does take some work, but there's a good explanation here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/diving-deep-into-angular-elements-c17a868d6894

Thank you very much! I'll try it and I'll let you know.

I will add an answer, it's too complicated in the comments

(Feedback: I don't have a view on whether the original question here was on topic, and I probably would not have cast a close vote myself. But the cut-down version seems to be rather more sparse, so I wonder if the trimming did not help make it more on topic).

You could use Angular custom elements (web components) to achieve this. I have a blog post about running AngularJS and Angular 17 side-by-side; this post is mostly about sharing state between the two, however, so it's not entirely relevant to your problem.
Setting up Angular custom elements does take some work, but there's a good explanation here.
The basic concept is that you would configure the Angular application as a custom element, compile it, and then provide the links to the JS bundles in index.php. Then, you would need to add the tags for your custom element to the index.php as HTML, like so:
  <script src="route-to-your-bundles/polyfills.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="route-to-your-bundles/main.js" type="module"></script>

  // Other HTML

  <angular18-app></angular18-app>

I am not a PHP expert, so I don't know if there's a better way to include the JS.

Could not have been more helpful. I'll try the entire procedure and I'll let you know.
